# Merge records depending on common columns and specify the values which are uncommon in the last column as comma separated

Tags: shell-script, awk, columns, merge

I need to merge records depending on first three common  columns and place the values  which are uncommon in the last column as comma separated . I have a requirement to do the following-

**InputFile :**

```
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    HelpPortalServer_1 
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_1
```

**Expected Output :**

```
ABC CommonDomain resourcebundle   AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain javatools       AdminServer,IHelpPortalServer_1 
HWF CommonDomain stringeditor   AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
```

Comment: Looking for help

Comment: Your data does not seem to match your description. Why does `oracle.javatools.resourcebundle` show on a line starting with ABC?  There's no ABC line in the input that contains that?  You should especially explain in detail what this means : "Merge records depending on common columns"

Comment: Edited the Input file and  Expected Output . Please check .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question, 100% better.

You didn't mention if the values in what you call "uncommon" values should be duplicated in the output, I assume not.

This script should run under all versions of `awk`.  *No GNU Extensions,* tested with `gawk --traditional`.  I've added extra input data to test more conditions.  This handles duplicate records in input.  The biggest problem I foresee would be commas in the input, the script will work as specified, but output file could appear to have empty fields, etc.

Description of code:

The `recs` array is indexed by the concatenation the first three fields. (Arrays in `awk` are indexed by strings.) Each element of the array contains what you call the "uncommon" fields separated by commas.

For every input line: `key` contains the first three fields.  The `for` loop steps through the remaining fields. The `if` statement checks to make sure the field has not yet been stored for this key.  If not, then the field is added to the end of the record, prepended by a space or comma, as appropriate.

At the end of input (`END` tag): Step through the keys to the recs array, printing the key and the data contained therein.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
    {
        key = $1 " " $2 " " $3;
        for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) {
            if (recs[key] !~ "(^|,)"$i"(,|$)") {
                recs[key] = recs[key] (recs[key] ? "," : "") $i
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in recs) {
            print key " " recs[key]
        }
    }
' <<EOF
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer2
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       3AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  AdminServer2
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  3AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    AdminServer2
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    3AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  HelpPortalServer
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    HelpPortalServer_1 
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_2
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       3_HelpPortalServer_2
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    HelpPortalServer 
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_2
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       3_HelpPortalServer
EOF
```

Output:

```
HWF CommonDomain stringeditor AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain javatools AdminServer,AdminServer2,3AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1,HelpPortalServer_2,3_HelpPortalServer_2
ABC CommonDomain resourcebundle AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
```

Comment: Thank You that worked . Can you briefly explain the code

Comment: Yes I'll add that to the answer but `man` `awk` would probably be sufficient. The script is very short.